# Integration site PHP / MySQL App with Phonegap

Tags: javascript, php, cordova

I am creating a website and an App with Phonegap, I'm new in programming for mobile platforms, this site has a database and want this bunch of data is directly available in the App, but do not want to access the database remotely, then how can I do to send a request to the PHP site and it returns me a result to be displayed in the App using JS? How can I make PHP and JS? And is to make a "cache" in the App DB, make a copy on a daily basis, or when updating the DB?

Answer (score 0):

ok well it depends how your site is setup. JS by default is client side, however you can do things like

```
document.getElementById('myiframe').src='phpscript.php';
```

thus refreshing the script inside of the frame, the script would pull the data from your database.

otherwise look into AJAX